# How to substract and round times

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, time, datetime-format

Q:

If i have two periods in the following format `.ToString("H:m");` and i wanna to firstly **subtract** the end period from the first period ,then **round** the result .like the following example:

> 13:00 ---->First period.
>
> 13.45 ---->Last period.

the result `45` ----> round to `60`

if the result = `75` for example then round to `120`

Comment: Is this just a really complicated way of saying that you want to round to the nearest minute?

Comment: What are the original types that you are calling "ToString" on? Why can't you use those?

Comment: the original is `string`

Comment: @just_name: He means what is the type of the object that `.ToString("H:m")` method is being called on? It clearly isn't a string since that doesn't support the format you've passed it.

Comment: hmmm i want to say that the original type is `string`and always like`"H:m"`

Comment: So, you are doing something like `"H:m".ToString("H:m")`? Really? Calling `ToString("H:m")` on a string will return "H:m".

Comment: no, I have a string . always in this format "H:m" `(digit:two digits)`

Comment: i don't call `.ToString("H:m")`. just wanna to say that the string always in this format.

Comment: Then say that. The way you phrased your question is very confusing.

Comment: sorry for this confusion.Could u rephrase the question if u want,please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
 var t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("13:00").TotalMinutes;
 var t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("13:45").TotalMinutes;
 var round = (1 + ((int)(t2 - t1) / 60)) * 60; //Assuming t2 is always greater than t1
```

Hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: this works ,thanks a lot . Could u explain the equation please?

Comment: t1 & t2 are `double`, so converted (t2 - t1) to `int`, now if this is 45, division by 60 will make result 0, and for 45 you want 60. Now if t2 - t1 is 75, division will be 1, and 75 will be rounded to 120.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime.parse to get two datetime objects for first and last period
then subtract them using lastperiod.subtract(firstperiod)
this will return u a timespan object
you can then round it as you want

Comment: -1 DateTime will work, but TimeSpan is more appropriate as @just_name has string in "H:m" format.

Comment: well, you can use datetime.parseexact(). u shud think before voting down mate